# Why aren't any of my boxes showing in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am coding a website for college coursework and I am writing it in DreamWeaver. When I go into design view it is all visible but when I view it in Safari or Chrome I can't see it at all. Please can you help me?

Please visit http://jsfiddle.net/NA6eN/ to see my code so far.

```
#wrapper
{
width: 90%;
margin: 0 auto;
color:#CCC;
}

 #top_box
 {
position: absolute;
min-width: 90%;
max-width: 90%;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 92%;
right: 5%;
background: white;
width: 80%;
border: 5px rgba(0, 239, 255, 0.5) solid;
border-top: none;
}
```

Comment: `<div id="wrapper"` : a `>`is missing in your fiddle. You should validate your code

Comment: There are a lot of closing `>` on some opening tags missing. Don't use dreamweaver or anything, if you want to do correct work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have so many missing `>` objects, that's why the error. Fix your html and try again and it works fine, like this:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">


<div id="top_box"></div>

<div class="background"></div>



<div id="menu_box">

</div>


<div id="main_box">

</div>


<div id="Bottom_box">

</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NA6eN/)**

Comment: Thank you @Hanky 웃 Panky! ill make sure it accept this answer when I can

Answer (score 1):

**Invaild** in your HTML code : (HTML opening/closing tags)

**Original :**

```
<div id="wrapper"
    <div id="top_box"></div>
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div id="menu_box" </div>
    <div id="main_box" </div>
    <div id="Bottom_box" </div>
</div>
```

**Fix to :**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top_box"></div>
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div id="menu_box"></div>
    <div id="main_box"></div>
    <div id="Bottom_box"></div>
</div>
```

**Trick in jsFiddle**

- click on [image] buttom for more readable
  [image]
- You see that code in red color ?, Its mean your HTML not vaild
- Fix it ! like your is missing closing tag , closing tag with no opening tag... bla bla bla

Result :

[image]

Vaild !

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/NA6eN/3/

**Useful tool for you :** http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close the wrapper div:

```
<div id="wrapper"
```

should be

```
<div id="wrapper">
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing to close `>`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/p6gfW/)**

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">


<div id="top_box"></div>

<div class="background"></div>



<div id="menu_box">

</div>


<div id="main_box">

</div>


<div id="Bottom_box">

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close your div's properly:

```
<div id="menu_box"
</div>
```

do it like this:

```
<div id="menu_box">
</div>
```

otherwise the browsers can't parse your html.

Fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/Z2k8d/

Answer (score 1):

You didnt end tag for div id wrapper

its

```
    <div id="wrapper"
```

now change it to

```
    <div id="wrapper">
```